# Should I use Toolbar on minSdkVersion 17 in Android?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I added for about 8 Months ago a `ActionBar` in my App.
Now that I've read that the `Toolbar` has more functionality I thought to add the `Toolbar` as `ActionBar`.

I've added this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/listview_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/kevox"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/MyActionBar" />
```

on `android:elevation="4dp"` I get the Message that this function is ignored in minSdkVersion=17.

That's how a Button is placed in Toolbar.
[image]

As you can see, the `MenuItem` like the `Button` does not fill the whole `Toolbar`.

Is it a good Idea to use a Toolbar in this SDK Version? As I saw in the statistics API 17-19 is still the most used Android-Version.

Comment: https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Comment: elevation works on lollipop and above. You can use toolbar with the support library. Toolbar is just like any other viewgroup

Comment: Thank you for the information! Can you tell me why the Button has some space in the bottom?